# Setting user permissions for a drive item to something other than role based {read, write, owner}

Tags: r, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to assign a [permission level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels) to a drive item?

My main goal is to let users read, but not download, the documents in the folder.

[image]

```r
library(Microsoft365R)

sp <- list_sharepoint_sites()

general_drive <- sp[[1]]$list_drives()[[2]]

general_drive$create_folder('test folder')

item <- general_drive$get_item('test folder')

my_body <- list(
  recipients = list(list(email= 'me@company.com')),
  sendInvitation = FALSE,  
  requireSignIn = TRUE,  
  roles = list('read')
  )

item$do_operation(op = 'invite', http_verb = 'POST', body = my_body)

# status 200

perms <- item$do_operation(op = 'permissions')

item$do_operation(op = file.path('permissions',perms$value[[6]]$id),
                  http_verb = 'PATCH', 
                  body = list(roles = c('read','write')))

# status 200

item$do_operation(op = file.path('permissions',perms$value[[6]]$id),
                  http_verb = 'PATCH', 
                  body = list(roles = c('resticted view')))

#> Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) : 
#>   Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to complete operation. Message:
#> [permissionInformation] An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A
#> 'StartArray' node was expected.

item$do_operation(op = file.path('permissions',perms$value[[6]]$id),
                  http_verb = 'PATCH', 
                  body = list(roles = list('restricted view')))

#> Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) : 
#>   Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to complete operation. Message:
#> Invalid value for role.
```

If I do set it manually on the site and then query what it is using the API I get back an empty list

```r
perms <- item$do_operation(op = 'permissions')
perms$value[[6]]
#> $id
#> [1] "aTowIy5mfG1lbWJlcnNoaXB8d2lsbGlhbS5oYXllc0BzYWdlcnguY29t"
#> 
#> $roles
#> list()
```